# Return to index in backbone.js router

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, url-routing

Just wanted to know, what is the proper way of returning to the index in backbone.js? So this is an outline of my code. I have a router, where it creates an instance of a view and passes the current instance of the router.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    callMasterViefw: function(){
        MasterView.initialize(this);
    },
})
```

Inside the `MasterView`, I create an instance of the `MasterView` and assign the router to it as well. I have a function, called `reRouteToIndex`, where basically i want to reroute to the index page.

```
MasterView= Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){},
    reRouteToIndex(){
        this.router.navigate("", {trigger: true,replace: true});
    },
});
```

All this works, but the problem is when I redirect to the index I return to something like `www.test.com/index.html/#`. Where it is important to note the # at the end. I was wondering if there was a way to route to the original path without the `#` like this `www.test.com/index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

You could enable `pushState` in `.navigate()`  (like `.navigate({pushState: true, trigger: true})` but you'll need to configure your webserver to work with `mod_rewrite` (or equivalent).